# Картинку и цвет фоном

Tags: css

Как наложить цвет поверх логотипа через CSS, как на картинке?[image: нужно, чтобы было так]

Comment: Svila food логотип, поверх прямоугольник, в фш определяется как черный цвет с прозрачностью 89%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<style>
.background{
background: url('background.jpg');
z-index: 1;
}
.information{
background:#00000099;
z-index:2;
}
</style>
<div class='background'></div>
<div class='information'>О нас в цифрах</div>
```

Примерно так